# Which files is KDE deleting?

Tags: filesystems, kde

I inadvertently started file deletion from KDE's Dolphin file manager. I noticed the mistake quickly and paused the process, but still in the 1–2 seconds a lot of files could have been gone. Now I'm trying to assess the damage – what have I lost.

Looking at the dialogue doesn't help:

[image]

It only tells me that it is deleting 3 files. Two of them I wanted to delete, the third is the directory `/home/ca/Store` it is currently busy with. But this directory contains thousands of subdirectories and ten-thousands of files.

Since I paused the process but didn't stop it, I thought there might still be a trace in memory, e.g. a list of files it is working through?

Debian 11, Plasma 5.20.5, Dolphin 20.12.2
The directory is on an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Look for a recycle bin called `Trash` on the desktop. It may be called `~/Desktop/trash.desktop` or `~.local/share/Trash/files`. It may also be hidden.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but unfortunately the files weren't trashed, they were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I did not succeed to extract the information from the running process, but I found that `locate` can help. On my system, `mlocate.db` is updated once a day. One can therefore get a list of files which existed before:

```bsh
locate Store | grep "^/home/ca/Store" > previous
```

then a version filtered for still existing files

```bsh
locate -e Store | grep "^/home/ca/Store" > current
```

and compare them to get a list of deleted files:

```bsh
comm -23 previous current > lost
```